# If any variable in a row is greater than a value, keep the row in R

Tags: r, subset

So, I have a code that works:

```
minimum_ozone <- 65

ozone <- subset(ozone, ozone[2] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[3] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[4] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[5] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[6] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[7] >= minimum_ozone
             | ozone[8] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[9] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[10] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[11] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[12] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[13] >= minimum_ozone
             | ozone[14] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[15] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[16] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[17] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[18] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[19] >= minimum_ozone
             | ozone[20] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[21] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[22] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[23] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[24] >= minimum_ozone | ozone[25] >= minimum_ozone)
```

However, this code seems like it is too bulky... is there a shorter code/faster way to execute this?

Comment: I'd love to know how this is "too broad." If it generates 2 working answers then I fail to see how this should be closed using that status. Okay, it could do with a reproducible `ozone` dataset, but the concept is straightforward.

Comment: I'm curious about why it's considered "too broad" as well.  Thanks for the solution @thelatemail!

Comment: I reworded the question, so that hopefully it will not be "too broad" any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a quick-running, vectorised fashion without explictly typing out each comparison. Here are a few options:

```
# compare the whole data.frame to min and sum the logical values in each row
res1 <- ozone[rowSums(ozone[2:5] >= minimum_ozone) > 0,]

# use pmax to get the row maximum and then compare to min
res2 <- ozone[do.call(pmax, ozone[2:5]) >= minimum_ozone,]

# use Reduce and | (or) to do the same process you wrote out long-hand
res3 <- ozone[Reduce(`|`, lapply(ozone[2:5], `>=`, minimum_ozone)),]
```

Test it with some made up data:

```
# example data
minimum_ozone <- 65
set.seed(1)
ozone <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(1:100,5)))
names(ozone) <- paste0("v",1:5)

# long-hand solution
out <- subset(
    ozone,
    ozone[2] >= minimum_ozone |
    ozone[3] >= minimum_ozone |
    ozone[4] >= minimum_ozone |
    ozone[5] >= minimum_ozone
)

identical(out, res1)
#[1] TRUE
identical(out, res2)
#[1] TRUE
identical(out, res3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: res3 worked great for a solution!  res1 and res 2 returned some rows with NA values across the entire row...

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(1)

ozone <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(40:70, 50, replace=TRUE), 10))
ozone
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  48 46 68 54 65
# 2  51 45 46 58 60
# 3  57 61 60 55 64
# 4  68 51 43 45 57
# 5  46 63 48 65 56
# 6  67 55 51 60 64
# 7  69 62 40 64 40
# 8  60 70 51 43 54
# 9  59 51 66 62 62
# 10 41 64 50 52 61

minimum_ozone <- 65
ozone[which(apply(ozone, 1, max) > minimum_ozone), ]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1 48 46 68 54 65
# 4 68 51 43 45 57
# 6 67 55 51 60 64
# 7 69 62 40 64 40
# 8 60 70 51 43 54
# 9 59 51 66 62 62
```